# Limit the Users using Policy Mangement

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

Can we limit the number of users (For ex. 5) for a particular login 
Or Is there anyway to restrict the particular User using POLICY MANAGEMENT in SQL SERVER?

Please kindly help me to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think it could be done with PBM, but you can solve this by creating a logon trigger, and in the trigger do a quick query on `sys.dm_exec_sessions`, counting sessions with the `original_login_name` same as `suser_sname()`.

Beware that an error in login trigger could prevent all logins and render the instance unaccessible. To fix this, start the service in single user mode (-m).

Hope it helps.

Comment: If memory serves, one of the examples in books online is this exactly, so you've got the code all ready to go!

Comment: I have done thisusing logon triggers. How about the triggers performance?

Comment: I've been using it to prevent logins from certain applications for some clients. Didn't notice any measurable impact on performance.